# Does Dropbox work ok with Ubuntu server 13.04?

Tags: server, dropbox

I run a minecraft server that stays in sync with Dropbox and currently i have been using Ubuntu desktop. I want to switch to Ubuntu server 13.04, I have been practicing with Ubuntu server somewhat.

I'm about to buy a vps from Digitalocean soon and was hoping i could have Dropbox working with Ubuntu server. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu server and Ubuntu desktop are basically the same, and uses the same packages. The difference are which packages are installed by default. 
So yes, everything that works in the desktop edition can be installed and used in the server edition.

And you might want to use the program `git-annex` instead of DropBox. As `git-annex` are open source, more secure and much more flexible than DropBox.